# How to replace back button in Material in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cosmicmind

I want to change behavior of back button and I replace back button of **Material** with new bar button like bellow:

```
let backButton: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "prev"), for: .normal)
    btn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33/2, height: 27/2)

    return btn
}()
```

In **viewDidLoad** function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backButton.action = { [weak self] in self?.showAlert() }
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
    navigationItem.backButton.isHidden = true
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButton]
}
```

But I can not click to **new back button** because it was coverred by **UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView**.

How can I replace back button with **Material**. I want to keep **Material** library because in other features of project I need **Material**.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: your issue resolved?

Comment: It has been fixed: [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/commit/7560013c51e6498598caf2084b3942e111fb37f0).  I really appreciate your help with my question.

Comment: please mark my answer as useful/accepted if u found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your `viewDidLoad()` method :

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden = YES
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.back(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.image = UIImage(named : "prev")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.accessibilityFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 33/2, height: 27/2)
```

Then define a function named `back` in your view controller,this function will perform the desired action for your new back button

```
func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Perform your custom action
    }
```

**Note** No need to define a separate button variable

**If `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.hidden = YES` doesnt works then replace it with `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;` **

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Material's back button not hiding.

Comment: Or you try this : `navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` ,first go with my displayed code, then make the changes if required

Comment: I made a fix for you in the `development` branch. If you make this an issue on github, I will update you once I release it in the master branch. Shouldn't be more than a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Using backButton.isHidden with leftViews containing the new custom IconButtom works for me, I'm using Material 2.17.0.

```
func setNavigation() {
        let backButton = IconButton(image: Icon.cm.arrowBack)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onBackTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        navigationItem.leftViews = [backButton]
        navigationItem.backButton.isHidden = true
    }
```